# Can't access event.state or event.gain of ACTIVEEVENT

Tags: python, pygame

I was writing a paused screen for my game, the paused screen will be activated whenever the pygame window loses focus, here is my code:

```py
import pygame
from sys import exit

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60

while True:
    screen.fill('Black')
    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            exit()

        if event.type == pygame.ACTIVEEVENT:
            if event.state == 0:
                # paused screen goes here

    pygame.display.update()
```

from the documentation I read, the event I should check for is `pygame.ACTIVEEVENT` and that event has 2 attributes: `event.gain` and `event.state`. However, when I tried to access one of them, it prompts an error:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.10.5)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\WorkDir\Dinosaur\test.py", line 20, in <module>
    if event.state == 0:
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'state'
```

I searched up answers online but I couldn't find any. I found a question that is somewhat related to this:

[In pygame for event.type == ACTIVEEVENT, where is the documentation on what the different event.state and event.gain parameters mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61488114/in-pygame-for-event-type-activeevent-where-is-the-documentation-on-what-the)

I tried the code from the accepted answer but the bug was still there:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "D:\WorkDir\Dinosaur\test.py", line 28, in <module>
>    main()
>  File "D:\WorkDir\Dinosaur\test.py", line 18, in main
>    if e.state & APPMOUSEFOCUS == APPMOUSEFOCUS:
> AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'state'
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you print the `ACTIVEEVENT` events, e.g. `print(f"Active Event {event}")` you're trying to handle, you'll see that the first one doesn't have `gain` or `state`. You can probably skip this event, using something like

```
elif event.type == pygame.ACTIVEEVENT:
    print(f"Active Event {event}")
    try:
        print(f"Event state: {event.state}")
    except AttributeError:
        pass
```

You should see something like:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Active Event <Event(32768-ActiveEvent {})>
Active Event <Event(32768-ActiveEvent {'gain': 1, 'state': 1})>
Active Event <Event(32768-ActiveEvent {'gain': 1, 'state': 0})>
Active Event <Event(32768-ActiveEvent {'gain': 0, 'state': 0})>
Active Event <Event(32768-ActiveEvent {'gain': 1, 'state': 0})>
Active Event <Event(32768-ActiveEvent {'gain': 0, 'state': 0})>
```

However, you're using the latest PyGame so you can use the more specific events like [WINDOWFOCUSGAINED](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html?highlight=WINDOWFOCUSGAINED) and WINDOWFOCUSLOST to toggle your paused state. Here's a minimal example:

```
import pygame
 
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 320))
pygame.init()

counter = 0
paused = False
run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        elif event.type == pygame.WINDOWFOCUSGAINED:
            print(f"Gain Focus {event}")
            paused = False
        elif event.type == pygame.WINDOWFOCUSLOST:
            print(f"Lost Focus {event}")
            paused = True

    screen.fill(pygame.Color("grey"))
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)  # limit to 60 FPS
    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Paused: {paused}, Counter {counter:,}")
    if not paused:
        counter += 1

pygame.quit()
```

The window will look like this when runninn:
[image]

You'll see console output like this:

```
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.18, Python 3.9.13)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Gain Focus <Event(32785-WindowFocusGained {'window': None})>
Lost Focus <Event(32786-WindowFocusLost {'window': None})>
Gain Focus <Event(32785-WindowFocusGained {'window': None})>
Lost Focus <Event(32786-WindowFocusLost {'window': None})>
Gain Focus <Event(32785-WindowFocusGained {'window': None})>
```